# Electric clothes dryer

Tags: wiring

I have a Whirlpool electric dryer (120/240 volt 60 hertz) that is about 5 feet away from the breaker box currently, but I'm remodeling and moving it to another room which is only about 30 or 40 feet away.

I was wondering if I could make a wire, keep it solid but make a wire out of my 10 2 wiring for this 240 dryer?

Comment: Using 10/2 wiring was *never* legal for dryers, because you cannot use the bare solid ground as a neutral.  A long, long time ago, it was allowed to use SE wire which is for *service entrances*,  and it does have a bare neutral, but that was an age when nothing was grounded, and 10/3 w/gnd was not readily available.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need to pull a 10/3 from the panel to your new dryer receptacle location

The old way of wiring dryers (NEMA 10-30 with the dryer's chassis grounded using the neutral) was a terrible kludge, and rather unsafe at that since a fault in the dryer circuit neutral will render the dryer's chassis live, right next to the most-likely-grounded washing machine.

Since you're putting in a new receptacle in a new location, you'll need to do it *right* and pull a 10/3 W/G cable from the breaker box to the new dryer location -- neutral to neutral bar, ground to ground bar or combination bar if they are combined in a main panel, and the two hots to the existing 30A breaker, with the breaker turned off for all this of course.  At the new receptacle location, a NEMA 14-30R will need to be fitted -- black and red to hots, white to neutral, and green or bare to ground.

Don't forget to change the dryer over to a 4-wire (NEMA 14-30P) cord and pull the dryer's bonding jumper while you're at it!  You'll also need to use a torque screwdriver to tighten the breaker and panel lugs to the manufacturer-specified torque value (printed on the labeling for the breaker and panel) -- this is required by 2017 NEC 110.14(D).